# How can i retrieve the value of this element and assert it after a change is done?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working on automating an area of a web page (not able to provide the webpage as the contents are confidential, although will try to give as much insight as possible).

This element has on it an html code preview that will change after some selections are done. Here is the page html of the element:

```
<div _ngcontent-hje-c241="" class="field" style="position: relative;">
  <pre _ngcontent-hje-c241="" class="code-pre">
    "
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset='utf'>
        <title></title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
        <style type='text/css'>body,html, #video {height:100%;margin:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#000;}</style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    
          
          window.onload = function(event) {
            var config = {containerID: 'video', Player: true, wmode: 'direct'};
            myplayer = new Test.embed('WmAl', config);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div id='video'></div>
      </body>
    </html>"
```

(I have edited and removed any confidentials parts of the string for the html, the html itself was not changed.)
I would need to get the value of the element I found through class="code-pre".

Here is what I have tried:

```
IWebElement htmlTest = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("code-pre"));
var defaultHtmlTestValue = htmlTest.GetAttribute("value");
Assert.IsFalse(htmlTest.Equals(defaultHtmlTestValue), "The html has not changed after the Http selection");
```

The assert passes, altho, i would like to see what is the value that is being taken, as i feel like is not taking the html example i am trying to get.

I have also used `Debug.Writeline(htmlTest)` to see if it worked, but i got "Internal error in the expression evaluator". This is also an issue i will be trying to fix.

I am quite new to automation and stack overflow. Please let me know if there is a way i can improve this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with the html previews but looks like the whole html code is just the inner text of an element with class `code-pre`.

try doing :

```
String htmlTest = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("code-pre")).getTex();
System.out.println(htmlTest);
Assert.assertTrue(htmlTest.Equals(defaultHtmlTestValue), "The html has not changed after the Http selection");
```

You can easily convert above java code into your language.

Comment: Thank you very much, my lack of experience was working with GetAtrribute while what i really needed was .Text. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Np. It might actually work with htmlTest.GetAttribute("innerText"); You can give it a try.